# PHP validate form on submission

Tags: php, forms

I have a form and in the page I have to validate if values are posted. But when I print the post array I am getting `Array ( )` outside the `if` condition.
When I try to use `print_r()` inside the `if` condition, it is not working. The code I am  using is below:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  print_r($_POST); // Not Working
}
?>
<form method="post" action="anotherpage.php">
<input type="text" name="course" />
<input type="text" name="location" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="GO"/>
</form>
```

I also tried using a hidden input inside the form and post it. It is also not working.

Comment: thats because you are posting the FORM to `anotherpage.php` - not to this page.

Comment: put the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... }` code on the `anotherpage.php`

Comment: is it possible to validate the form in the same page before sending the values to another page

Comment: Yes absolutely. But you have to do it with JavaScript, not with PHP. JavaScript will validate it here on this page before sending it to anotherpage

Comment: use required in html block and jquery to validate user input before submitting it to another page for processing

Answer (score 0):

Your form is POSTing to `anotherpage.php`, not to the same page.

You can either change your `<form>` to post to the same page:

```
<form method="post">
...
</form>
```

Or put your PHP code in `anotherpage.php`:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```